# Dovecot fails to authenticate for some users

Tags: authentication, dovecot, imap

I've the typical Dovecot + Postfix setup, with Apache and Roundcube (in a VPS). Yesterday I set up everything, and it went smooth. Right, but today I woke up with the surprise that **some** users simply can't login. Clients give a message like this (roundcube case):

```
Login failed for $user from $ip. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed.
```

The worst of all is that some other users can log in, which is weird, since authentication methods, etc are global. I searched all over the internet for solutions, but nothing. I read the Dovecot wiki about password schemes, password databases, authentications mechanisms, etc. Whenever I try to login using telnet/openssl, I get:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.domain.tld:143 -starttls imap
a login $user $password
a NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

And the most insane part is that passwords are correct! passdb and userdb are correctly set up (they worked in previous servers I had, and confirmed it with `doveadm user` and `doveadm user`). And if that was not much, **the logs do not say anything!!** (even with the most verbose configuration, debugging enabled, etc.)

Here is my dovecot configuration:

```
$ dovecot -n
# 2.2.29.1 (e0b76e3): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.18 (29cc74d)
# OS: Linux 4.9.155-gnu-0-lts x86_64  
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login cram-md5
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_plugins = " quota"
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character         vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/passwd-file
  auth_verbose = yes
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  quota = maildir:Cuota de usuario
  quota_warning = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  inet_listener lmtp {
    port = 24
  }
  user = root
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 !SSLv3
userdb {
  args = /etc/passwd-file
  auth_verbose = yes
  driver = passwd-file
}
verbose_ssl = yes
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = " quota imap_quota imap_sieve"
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
}
protocol pop3 {
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
}
protocol sieve {
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " quota sieve"
}
```

Please help me, this is getting me mad :/

Comment: With `auth_verbose = yes`, `auth_verbose_passwords = plain`, `auth_debug_passwords = yes` you will get logging with passwords. If not your config is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the domain was pointing to a different IPv4 address, which was from another server with similar setup (that's why I thought it was the same server that I was talking about). This other server had a cronjob to automatically update the IPv4 address for my domains from my CloudFlare DNS (because I had a dynamic IP address in this server).